# Join Predicate Not Valid (SQL0338)

Tags: sql

please help me, I got the Join Predicate not valid error for the below sql, it will be very messy but please help me if you can. Thanks in advance.

```
SELECT department.eaaitm, 
       RIGHT(LEFT(egacdt, 6), 2), 
       SUM(CASE department.eaaitm 
             WHEN '912' THEN egacam / 2 
             ELSE egacam 
           END) AS suma, 
       SUM(CASE department.eaaitm 
             WHEN '700' THEN CASE data.eaaicl 
                               WHEN '400' THEN -egacam 
                               WHEN '402' THEN -egacam 
                               WHEN '404' THEN -egacam 
                               ELSE egacam 
                             END 
             WHEN '912' THEN egacam / 2 
             ELSE egacam 
           END / cuarat) 
FROM   mvxcdtpusd.fchacc department, 
       mvxcdtpusd.fchacc data 
       LEFT JOIN mvxcdtpusd.fgledg 
         ON data.eaaitm = egait1 
            AND data.eacono = 888 
            AND data.eaaitp = 1 
            AND egcono = 888 
            AND ( egdivi = ? 
                  AND ( data.eadivi = ? 
                         OR data.eadivi = '' ) ) 
            AND ( egdivi = ? 
                  AND ( department.eadivi = ? 
                         OR department.eadivi = '' ) ) 
            AND egacdt >= ? 
            AND egacdt <= ? 
       JOIN mvxcdtpusd.ccurra 
         ON ( cudivi = ( CASE egdivi 
                           WHEN '300' THEN egdivi 
                           ELSE '100' 
                         END ) 
              AND cucucd = 'USD' 
              AND LEFT(cucutd, 6) = LEFT(egacdt, 6) 
              AND ( ( cudivi = '300' 
                      AND cucrtp = '50' ) 
                     OR ( cudivi <> '300' 
                          AND culocd = 'USD' 
                          AND cucrtp = '1' ) ) 
              AND RIGHT(cucutd, 2) = '01' ) 
WHERE  egait3 = department.eaaitm 
       AND department.ealccd IN ( 0, 1 ) 
       AND department.eacono = 888 
       AND department.eaaitp = 3 
       AND data.eaaicl >= '400' 
       AND ( department.eaaitm IN ( '000' ) 
              OR department.eaaitm IN ( '912' ) 
                 AND data.eaaitm NOT IN ( '5707310' ) 
              OR department.eaaitm IN ( '914', '808' ) 
                 AND data.eaaitm NOT IN ( '5707310' ) ) 
GROUP  BY department.eaaitm, 
          RIGHT(LEFT(egacdt, 6), 2) 
ORDER  BY department.eaaitm, 
          RIGHT(LEFT(egacdt, 6), 2)
```

----------------------------------- Ans:-----------------------------------
i have solved already. Thanks All

```
 SELECT department.eaaitm,
       RIGHT(LEFT(egacdt, 6), 2),
       SUM(CASE department.eaaitm
             WHEN '912' THEN egacam / 2
             ELSE egacam
           END) AS suma,
       SUM(CASE department.eaaitm
             WHEN '700' THEN CASE data.eaaicl
                               WHEN '400' THEN -egacam
                               WHEN '402' THEN -egacam
                               WHEN '404' THEN -egacam
                               ELSE egacam
                             END
             WHEN '912' THEN egacam / 2
             ELSE egacam
           END / cuarat)
FROM   mvxcdtpusd.fchacc department,
       mvxcdtpusd.fchacc data
       LEFT JOIN mvxcdtpusd.fgledg
         ON data.eaaitm = egait1
            AND data.eacono = 888
            AND data.eaaitp = 1
            AND egcono = 888
            AND ( egdivi = 100
                  AND ( data.eadivi = 100
                         OR data.eadivi = '' ) )
            AND egacdt >= 20120101
            AND egacdt <= 20120131
       JOIN mvxcdtpusd.ccurra
         ON ( cudivi = ( CASE egdivi
                           WHEN '300' THEN egdivi
                           ELSE '100'
                         END )
              AND cucucd = 'USD'
              AND LEFT(cucutd, 6) = LEFT(egacdt, 6)
              AND ( ( cudivi = '300'
                      AND cucrtp = '50' )
                     OR ( cudivi <> '300'
                          AND culocd = 'USD'
                          AND cucrtp = '1' ) )
              AND RIGHT(cucutd, 2) = '01' )
WHERE  egait3 = department.eaaitm
       AND department.ealccd IN ( 0, 1 )
       AND department.eacono = 888
       AND department.eaaitp = 3
       AND data.eaaicl >= '400'
       AND ( department.eaaitm IN ( '000' )
              OR department.eaaitm IN ( '912' )
                 AND data.eaaitm NOT IN ( '5707310' )
              OR department.eaaitm IN ( '914', '808' )
                 AND data.eaaitm NOT IN ( '5707310' ) )
       AND ( egdivi = 100
             AND ( department.eadivi = 100
                    OR department.eadivi = '' ) )
GROUP  BY department.eaaitm,
          RIGHT(LEFT(egacdt, 6), 2)
ORDER  BY department.eaaitm,
          RIGHT(LEFT(egacdt, 6), 2)
```

Comment: It would be better if you can indent these code first. Look [here](http://www.dpriver.com/pp/sqlformat.htm).

Comment: please reformat so we don't have to scroll around.

Comment: Mixing comma-joins with other join syntax is not allowed in some RDBMSs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what system you are using to pass parameters to your query but I imagine it replaces the question marks (?) shown below

```
AND ( egdivi = ? 
              AND ( data.eadivi = ? 
                     OR data.eadivi = '' ) ) 
        AND ( egdivi = ? 
              AND ( department.eadivi = ? 
                     OR department.eadivi = '' ) ) 
        AND egacdt >= ? 
        AND egacdt <= ?
```

In any case the error you are getting is because one of those is not right.  Please show how you are passing parameters to this query.

Comment: @avamoe So...the error is in which part?

Comment: @cctam - my guess, he did not know he needed values there.  Probably a homework assignment.

Comment: i have solved .thanks for yr respond.